# jquery .net not firing the function $.ajax

Tags: c#, jquery

im using jquery in asp.net, if i try to use $.ajax functionality, i got this

1. if i use it in a separate page it works..
2. when i put it in an ascx and put the ascx out of `<form runat="server" >`... tags it works
3. if i put it between `<form>` tags , jquery works but it doesnt fire `$.ajax` event

Answer (score 1):

In my experience most jQuery code should go in $(document).ready(),
this is so that the DOM has loaded and the content is there,
have you tried that?
There is some good info on that [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29).

If that dosen't work, maybe post some code you are using?

HTH

Answer (score 0):

ive solved it. the problem was with asp .net master pages, there are many ways of sending a post-get request from jquery in ajax, but it seems only some of them work in asp .net, ive posted the code for a chat control in c# in http://code.google.com/p/micachat/

an example that works for get request

```
$.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
         },
        type: "GET",
        url: "./chatControl/processmessage.aspx?idportal=<%=Request["idportal"] %>",
        data: "message=" + $('#message').val() + "&name=" + $('#name').val() + "",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(msg){ $("#myDiv").text( "Data Received: " + msg ); }
        }); // end of ajax
```